# SQL Query for each date in a range

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I currently have an SQL query that looks like this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(5,1),(
    CONVERT(DECIMAL(6,1),(
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM Requests
        LEFT JOIN RequestSLA ON Requests.RequestId = RequestSLA.RequestId
        WHERE DateLogged between '2015/03/01' and '2015/08/17'
        AND RespondBy <= Responded
    ))/CONVERT(DECIMAL(6,1),(
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM Requests
        WHERE DateLogged between '2015/03/01' and '2015/08/17'
    )))
*100)
```

This returns the percentage of tickets that breached their responded SLA (where Responded is after RespondBy) for all tickets in the range of dates supplied. Is it possible to adapt this query to show the percentage for each day separately? I.E. something like this:

```
Date       Percentage
2015-03-01  10
2015-03-02  7
```

etc...

I tried using a `GROUP BY`clause, but this didn't work because the DateLogged (which is what I would be grouping by) is not included in the output of the statement

Comment: why the two `CONVERT()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a single query rather than two correlated sub-selects, then you can use `GROUP BY DateLogged`, you just need to put a case expression within one of your counts:

```
SELECT  r.DateLogged,
        Total = COUNT(*),
        BreachedSLA = COUNT(CASE WHEN sla.RespondBy <= sla.Responded THEN 1 END),
        PercentBreached = CONVERT(DECIMAL(6, 1), 100.0 * COUNT(CASE WHEN sla.RespondBy <= sla.Responded THEN 1 END) / COUNT(*))
FROM    Requests AS r
        LEFT JOIN RequestSLA AS sla
            ON r.RequestId = sla.RequestId
WHERE   r.DateLogged >= '20150301'
AND     r.DateLogged <= '20150817'
GROUP BY r.DateLogged;
```

N.B, I have changed your date format to the completely culture independent format `yyyyMMdd`, this is the only independent format for `DATETIME` and `SMALLDATETIME` in SQL Server, so although marginally less legible, it guarantees correct conversion, with certain regional settings the format `yyyy/MM/dd` will throw an error, or worse it will be converted to an unintended date.

```
SET DATEFORMAT DMY;
SELECT  CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015/08/17')
```

I have also changed your `BETWEEN` clause to `>=` and `<=`, not because it is any different, but because it is easier to convert to an open ended date range, e.g.

```
WHERE   r.DateLogged >= '20150301'
AND     r.DateLogged < '20150818'
```

With `between '2015/03/01' and '2015/08/17'`, you might get a date logged of `2015/08/17 10:00`, that isn't being returned, and it is often not intuitive as to why. For more reading see [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common).

Comment: Liking the name of that sqlblog article. I've just found that I may need to query a second set of table for any 'closed' tickets. Could this be done by adding a `UNION SELECT` just above the final WHERE clause, and duplicating the columns to select, or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: sholdn't you use a `count(distinct r.RequestId)` instead of `count(*)` ?

Comment: I should also point out that you want `sla.Responded`, not `r.Responded`

Comment: @Aツ RequestId is unique, so it shouldn't affect the results, and I don't think it'll affect performance

Comment: i assumed there may be more than one sla records per record

Comment: I've updated the query, had to guess as to which table which field from `RespondBy <= Responded` belonged to, and guessed wrong....  I think a further left join would probably suffice to get closed requests (assuming you can also link on `RequestID`?

Comment: @Aツ no, but for some reason this software splits the data for a single ticket across 3 different tables...

Comment: @GarethD I'm not sure if that would work, it's essentially a duplicated set of tables with the same structure as Requests and RequestSLA called ArchiveRequests and ArchiveReqSLA. Any ticket that hasn't been modified within a certain time gets moved from the main table into the archive table

Comment: Also, shouldn't `PercentWithin` be `PercentBreach`?